# React Navigation. Prop route.params in children component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I actually have this in my code

```
<Tab.Screen
   name="Profile"
   children={() => <ProfileStacks scrollRef={profileScrollRef} />}
   options={{
      tabBarColor: colors.white,
   }}
/>
```

I need to pass props to the component "ProfileStacks" but also need to access route.params.

The problem is that I can't get this using "children". Instead, if I use

```
<Tab.Screen
   name="Profile"
   children={ProfileStacks}
   options={{
      tabBarColor: colors.white,
   }}
/>
```

I can perfectly access route.params, but can't pass the props.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone need this the solution is just doing:

```
<Tab.Screen
   name="Profile"
   children={(props) => <ProfileStacks route={props.route} scrollRef={profileScrollRef} />}
   options={{
      tabBarColor: colors.white,
   }}
/>
```